# Problem to diplay a 3d mesh using alphahull >0 with plotly in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, plotly, alpha-shape

I tried the following example [3D Mesh example with AlphaNull](https://plotly.com/python/3d-mesh/) to test alphahull but my jupyter notebook display just something blank.

When I set `alphahull=5`, the display is blank:
[image: result for alphahull=5]

But when i set `alphahull = 0`, it works:
[image: result for alphahull = 0]

and when i set `alphahull = -1`, it works :
[image: result for alphahull = -1]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think rendering for alphahull values larger than 0 may be broken as of the latest plotly update. I noticed that in the [documentation page](https://plotly.com/python/3d-mesh/#3d-mesh-example-with-alphahull), their code example with `alphahull=5` also doesn't render. I tried with other positive values and none of these render either (the same [alpha shape algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape) is used for any alphanull > 0)

However, I tried downgrading to `plotly==4.14.0` and the same example with `alphahull=5` does render.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

pts = np.loadtxt(np.DataSource().open('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/mesh_dataset.txt'))
x, y, z = pts.T

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Mesh3d(x=x, y=y, z=z,
                   alphahull=5,
                   opacity=0.4,
                   color='cyan')])
fig.show()
```

[image]

So in your jupyter notebook, you can run the line `!pip install plotly==4.14.0` in a separate cell and see if that allows you to render positive alphahull values.

Comment: Thank you @Derek-o it works with this version !

Comment: Which versions of python, jupyter etc did you use? I had the same issue, and using plotly 4.14.0 doesn't help